# forkJoin not binding data to front end in Angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs, fork-join

I need to make multiple `HTTP` requests from my component to load different sections in the front end.

The requests need to be made one after the other, so I used `forkJoin` to achieve this.

I'm successfully getting data as expected. But the data is not loading in the front end. When I make separate calls instead of using `forkJoin` I'm getting data and the views are also bound with the data.

Here is my code:

**TS file**

```
res1: string;
res2: string;
res3: string;
res4: string;
res5: string;

getDetails() {

   forkJoin(
        this.http.get(url1, { params: params1 }).pipe(map((res:Response) => res)),
        this.http.get(url2, { params: params2 }).pipe(map((res:Response) => res)),
        this.http.get(url3, { params: params3 }).pipe(map((res:Response) => res)),
        this.http.get(url4, { params: params4 }).pipe(map((res:Response) => res)),
        this.http.get(url5, { params: params5 }).pipe(map((res:Response) => res))

    ).subscribe(
      data => {

         this.res1 = JSON.stringify(data[0]);
         this.res2 = JSON.stringify(data[1]);
         this.res3 = JSON.stringify(data[2]);
         this.res4 = JSON.stringify(data[3]);
         this.res5 = JSON.stringify(data[4]);

    },
      error => {
                 console.log(error.toString());                  
    });
}
```

**HTML file**

```
<p>{{ res1 }}</p>
<p>{{ res2 }}</p>
<p>{{ res3 }}</p>
<p>{{ res4 }}</p>
<p>{{ res5 }}</p>
```

Comment: what is the expected output data of each `res`?

Comment: Can you see the request and response properly in network tab when using forkJoin?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see specifict reason which causes problem.

I produced working code in StackBlitz from your code

Check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rz1qn1

Note: I have used `import { forkJoin, from } from 'rxjs';`

Answer (score 0):

I feel so dumb right now. I forgot to change one boolean variable to display data which was missed out in my forkJoin subscribe method.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to use `Observable.forkJoin` instead.

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

Observable.forkJoin(obsArray)
  .subscribe((res) => {
    ...
```

## <kbd>[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forkjoin?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts)</kbd>